# convert comma separated values into a list of values using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cut

I have csv data like:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

I want this data in a list, one letter in each line. Is it possible is shell script? I have tried to extract each letter using cut command as shown below:

```
less list.txt | cut -d"," -f?
```

The command is working but the problem here is the number of fields is unknown. I have to place this command in a loop and iterate on the list so that I can extract the values one-by-one a redirect them to another file.

Comment: You should post some code and point to with what you are have problems, this will make it a lot easier for other to help you solve it.

Comment: Side point: it's odd to pipe your file into your command using `less`.  More conventional would be `cut file`, `cut < file`, or, if you really want to use a pipe, `cat file | cut`.  If less did its usual job, you'd have to keep hitting the spacebar to finish, but actually, it notices that standard output is not your screen, and basically turns itself into `cat` for you.

Answer (score 17):

Use `tr` to change `,` into newlines:

```
tr , "\n" < list.txt
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)

Comment: Btw, [here's your command outputting the OP's request (with an echo instead)](http://ideone.com/yxyM88).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `tr` command to transform each "," into a newline.

```
cat list.txt | tr "," "\n"
```

From then you can output each line wherever you want using a while read loop

```
cat list.txt | tr "," "\n" | while read LINE
 do
  echo "$LINE" >> ~/wherever/you/want
done
```

Or ...

```
while read LINE
 do
  echo "$LINE" >> ~/wherever/you/want
done <<< "$(cat list.txt | tr "," "\n")"
```

Either works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
sed "s/,/\n/g" list.txt
```

**Output**

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But it doesn't do harm, does it?

Comment: neither does writing `sed -r -s -u -l10000 --posix -e "s/,/\n/g"`. Still pointless though.

Comment: The value in using `-e` is that if the sed script ever needs to start with a `-` (which may or may not actually be possible) you won't need to remember to add `-e` and if you ever want to add a second script to the command you can just add `-e <script>` to the end without needing to go add `-e` before the first script. That said it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm pretty sure it would be a syntax error if you started with a `-`.  My point was that it is a single script that doesn't begin like that. I understand when `-e` can be useful, just like all the flags in my other comment "can" be useful, just not in this case.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, because that is it's purpose, obviously the other flags aren't going to do that, they are all useful though in situations that demand them. It's like saying `-r` should be there so you don't have to remember to add it if you start using ERE. But OP is not and neither of them is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `cut`. The key point is the usage of `--output-delimiter`. If you set it as new line, everything works:

```
cut -d',' --output-delimiter=$'\n' -f1- file
```

Note also two facts:

- we use `-f1-` to print from the first field up to the last one. The `n-` syntax means: from the n-th field up to the end.
- we use `$'\n'` because `\n` alone would print literal `\n` instead of real new lines.

#### Test

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h" | cut -d',' --output-delimiter=$'\n' -f1-
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

From `man cut`:

> **--output-delimiter=STRING**
>
> use STRING as the output delimiter the default is to use the input
>   delimiter

Comment: @Armfoot thanks, even though it is something I am already posting in my answer. That is, I don't see what value this is adding. But thanks for your support

Comment: ah... it's just a real test/fiddle/confirmation is much nicer to the one who's going to use it ;)